# Returns json result and convert null to empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action that returns json result, but some of the attributes are null and I want to convert them to empty strings instead. I heard I can use `DefaultValue("")`, but it's still returning `null` instead of empty string.

The action is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetResults(string date)
{
    var data= GetData();  // returns List<Foo>
    var json = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return json;
}
```

The `Foo` class is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar1;

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public int? Bar2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Dave A noticed you can not assign string value to the int value.

However one thing that I wanted to warn it, have you set properly the property `DefaultValueHandling`? Check it here: [Removing Default Values in JSON with the MVC4 Web API](http://macroface.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/removing-default-values-in-json-with-the-mvc4-web-api/)

Besides that I would recommend  to you that you do a string property that represent this Bar2 int property and you "Ignore" it for serialization, like:

```
[JsonIgnore]
[DefaultValue(0)]
public int? Bar2Int;

public string Bar2
{
   return { Bar2Int.HasValue ? this.Bar2Int.Value.ToString() : String.Empty; }
}
```

Even better with this approach you do not need any default values attributes.

Comment: very interesting implementation. I'll study and make use of it.

Comment: @Dave A: Tnx! I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

you can't set a `nullable int` to default val of `""`

Try

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
public int? Bar2;
```